# CIRCULAR JQUERY HORIZONTAL SCROLLER

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like to modify this scroller to loop continously in a circular fashion rather then wait for the last element and then begin to scroll again.

```
jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
           travelocity: 0.07
        }, settings);       
        return this.each(function(){
                var $strip = jQuery(this);
                $strip.addClass("newsticker")
                var stripWidth = 20;
                $strip.find("li").each(function(i){
                   stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
                });
                var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
                var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");                             
                var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width();  //a.k.a. 'mask' width   
                $strip.width(stripWidth);           
                var totalTravel = stripWidth+containerWidth;
                var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity;   // thanks to Scott Waye     
                function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
                   $strip.animate({left: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});//defTiming
                }
                scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);             
                $strip.hover(function(){
                   jQuery(this).stop();
                },
                function(){
                   var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                   var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
                   var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
                   scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
                });         
        }); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery plugin named simplyscroll might be what you're looking for: 
http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html